# Wpf conditional trigger based on combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

In my `DataGrid` I've binded an enum to the following `ComboBox`:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbDbType" Style="{StaticResource CmbStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EnumDbType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=userControls:ViewerOptions}}" SelectedValue="{Binding DbType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Values are several, such "MDB", "SQL"...
Now I want to show an icon based on selection ("SQL) of the `ComboBox` previously declarated:

```
    <Button x:Name="btnSelectPath" Width="Auto" Command="classes:SpvCommands.SelezionePath" ToolTip="Select Path">
    <Grid Height="20">
        <Image x:Name="imgFolder" Source="Icons/folder.png" Width="16" Height="16" Visibility="Visible" />
        <Image x:Name="imgDb" Source="Icons/db.png" Width="16" Height="16" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </Grid>
</Button>
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cmbDbType, Path=SelectedValue}" Value="SQL">
        <Setter TargetName="imgFolder" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
        <Setter TargetName="imgDb" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

But nothing change, the default icon, "folder" always appear. Any hints?

Comment: Bind to the source property (DbType) instead of binding to the ComboBox element. Where is the Button located?

Comment: If I bind the DbType (as I previously done), the value is not what I choose from Combobox, so I can't condition the view of icons

Comment: Then your binding doesn't work or you don't raise change notifications as you should.

Answer (score 1):

You should bind to the `DbType` source property instead of binding to a `ComboBox` element that is defined in a `DataTemplate`.

Provided that the `Button` is defined in the same `DataGrid` and that your data object implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event and raises the `PropertyChanged` event for the `DbType` property, the following should work:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DbType}" Value="{x:Static local:YourEnum.SQL}">
    <Setter TargetName="imgFolder" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter TargetName="imgDb" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: yes, but button and combobox are in the same datagrid. The combobocx is also defined in another column

Comment: Then this should work provided that you raise change notifications as I mentioned in the answer. No one can tell whether you do unless you post your actual code.